# Parse Column Data in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, ssms

I have a column of events that are formatted as shown:

```
Production-PMPO_1-2017-02-14 15:30:00.000
```

Can I parse out the beginning either in SQL Server Management Studio or in VS (vb.net) to make it have `DateTime` only?

Such as `2017-02-14 15:30:00`

Comment: Are they always prefixed with `Production-PMPO_1-`?

Comment: Yes, you can. Some usage of `charindex` as well as `substring` will do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the datetime part is always 23 characters long you can use [`RIGHT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
SELECT RIGHT(x.Col, 23) as dt
FROM (SELECT 'Production-PMPO_1-2017-02-14 15:30:00.000' as Col) x
```

With VB.NET you could use `Substring`:

```
Dim dt As String = str.Substring(str.Length - 23)
```

Comment: Upvote from my side, but I would add `CONVERT(DATETIME,RIGHT(...),120)` to get a `datetime` back

Comment: @Shnugo: or store it in a `datetime`-column in the first place ;)

Comment: Absolutely true... I'm sure, that the reason for this question is the deep wish to get this sorted :-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter is it possible to create a view that changes a table column from nvarchar to datetime?

Comment: @Dplusa25: sure, a view is like a query. You can cast the substring to `datetime`. But you should really change your datamodel instead and store it in a separate datetime column in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If `Production-PMPO_1-` is fixed,then you can do it by just replacing it with empty string.

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(100)='Production-PMPO_1-2017-02-14 15:30:00.000'
SELECT REPLACE(@a,'Production-PMPO_1-','');
```